# Global contact list / roster in ejabberd

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

How can I create a global roster for any new registered user in ejabberd ?

I want to add user to the roster as soon as it is registered.

I cannot use the shared roster list as i want a one-to-many relationship sort of thing.

user(admin)<->all users.

Answer (score 0):

ejabberd shared roster support is not necessarily symmetric.
You can define shared roster where admin is autorized to see presence of all users and not the reverse.
Please, check ejabberd shared_roster documentation: https://git.process-one.net/ejabberd/mainline/blobs/raw/v2.1.11/doc/guide.html#modsharedroster

If you use special alias, like @all@, the shared roster will be purely dynamic and will include all users on the server at retrieval time.

Comment: I updated the answer to make clear that shared roster are dynamic.